# Appropinquare: difference in the meaning according to the case?

Tags: meaning, preposition, case

Is there a difference in the meaning, between "appropinquare" + dative,
and "appropinquare" + ad + accusative?

Dictionaries are not very clear about it.

https://outils.biblissima.fr/fr/collatinus-web/

Comment: "Dictionaries are not very clear about it" because the **conceptual scene** referred to by "_appropinquare_ + dative" and "_appropinquare_ + _ad_-accusative" is the SAME. However, their **structural meaning**, i.e., the one associated to grammar, can be claimed to be different (see below).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my view, there is a subtle difference in meaning. Crucially, note that the adjective *propinquus*, which expresses a **state**, selects a dative (e.g., [*in propinquis urbi montibus*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0136%3Alife%3Dhan.%3Achapter%3D5%3Asection%3D1) (Nep. *Han.* 5.1)). So the dative nominal associated to the verb *appropinquare*, which is derived from the adjective *propinquus*, is used to express the final static position attained by the subject: i.e., at the end of the motion event encoded in *appropinquare*, the nominative [Figure](http://scodis.com/for-students/glossary/figure-and-ground/) subject is *propinquus* 'near to' the dative [Ground](http://scodis.com/for-students/glossary/figure-and-ground/) object.

In contrast, the Prepositional Phrase formed by *ad* plus an accusative noun is related to **dynamic** motion + path (*ad-*) event associated with the verb *appropinquare* rather than to the inner **stative** adjective *propinquus* incorporated in this verb.

NB I: hopefully, my answer above can also be regarded as a sort of up-date of what I consider an interesting intuition found in this [link](https://books.google.es/books?id=7DECAAAAQAAJ&pg=RA1-PA83&lpg=RA1-PA83&dq=Appropinquare%20dative&source=bl&ots=m5dkCaRZiK&sig=ACfU3U2UO0xi5V3Qrcy90pYGV3oOOTgANw&hl=ca&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjulvCSvPTlAhUNdxoKHbUlDsA4ChDoATABegQICBAB#v=onepage&q=Appropinquare%20dative&f=false).

NB II: alternatively, if you don't find the explanation above convincing, you could try to explore the connection between the dative of *appropinquare* and the so-called "directional dative": e.g., *It clamor **caelo*** (Virg. *Aen.* 5.451). The problem with this alternative is that this kind of directional dative is typically reduced to poetry. This construction is very rarely found in prose, where *It clamor ad caelum* is expected.

NB III: a second alternative would be to explore the well-known connection between [prefixed verbs and datives](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/dative-compounds). For a recent work and useful references therein, see also [this paper](https://ddd.uab.cat/pub/cjol/cjol_a2017v16/cjol_a2017v16p19.pdf). In my view, this second alternative can be claimed to apply to examples like *ubi adequitavit portis* (Liv. 22.42) but not to *appropinquare urbi* (Liv. 3.8.8). As pointed out above, the latter verb incorporates an adjective that **already** assigns dative. Furthermore, the difference between *adequitare* and *appropinquare* can be elucidated by the fact that the unprefixed variant of the former is incompatible with a dative (cf. the ill-formedness of **equitare portis*), whereas the unprefixed variant of the latter is compatible with the dative (cf. the well-formedness of *domui ignis propinquat* (Tac. *Ann.* 15, 39)). The motion event of both *appropinquare* and *propinquare* incorporates the stative adjective *propinquus*, which is, as claimed above, the true assigner of the dative case.